# Make Localhost a Custom Domain in IIS Express

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-7.5, iis-express

I am using IIS Express in Visual Studio 2010 and right now it runs on localhost:61156. But I need it to run on a domain. Is it possible to make IIS Express to run on devserver.com, instead of localhost:61156? So basically when I run debug I want devserver,com, instead of localhost:61156. I've come across a few things on google, but no luck. Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Do the following

1. If IIS Express is running stop it
2. Open your webapplication project file (*.csproj or *.vbproj)
3. Find `<IISUrl>http://localhost:61156/</IISUrl>` and change it to <`IISUrl>http://devserver.com:61156/</IISUrl>`
4. Open %userprofile%\documents\iisexpress\config\applicationhost.config file
5. **Visual Studio 2015 now puts an applicationhost.config file specific to your project instead of using the global one. It is located at: */path/to/code/root/.vs/config/applicationhost.config***
6. Find your site entry in applicationhost.config file change the binding as shown below
   `<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:61156:devserver.com" />`
7. In \Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file add following mapping "`127.0.0.1 devserver.com`"
8. In your browser add exception to bypass proxy for devserver.com
9. Note that, since you are using custom domain (non localhost binding), you must run visual studio as Administrator

Comment: Thanks! I don't seem to have a csproj file. Is there another file I can make that change in?

Comment: If you are using 'Visual Basic', you would find project file with  '.vbproj' extension. '.csproj' is extension for C-sharp projects.

Comment: thanks, im using C#. But I'm getting the files from SVN and csproj isnt part of it.

Comment: Love these answers that are clear and add all the steps necessary to make it work

Comment: It's kind of lame that you have to run VS as an administrator though. Is there any way around that?

Comment: Why do you need step 7 and can you give more information on how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

@vikomall's answer is the correct one, but I don't have enough reputation to comment yet, so I'm adding an extra answer here with a clarification for Visual Studio 2015.

Visual Studio 2015 now puts an applicationhost.config file specific to your project instead of using the global one.  It is located at:
/path/to/code/root/.vs/config/applicationhost.config

Follow the same steps as @vikomall's answer, but use the path above for step #4.

[See Mike Dice's Blog](https://mikedice417.wordpress.com/2015/09/13/vs-2015-and-you-must-specify-localhost-for-the-server-name/)