# Make Localhost a Custom Domain in IIS Express on port 80

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-7.5, iis-express

I followed [Make Localhost a Custom Domain in IIS Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249633/make-localhost-a-custom-domain-in-iis-express/11250513#comment28601044_11250513) to run my website in custom domain. When I tried to run the application in Port 80, I got an error from Visual studio saying 'Port 80 already in use. Cannot start IISExpress'

Is there any extra step that has to be done for port 80? (I was able to run the application in some other ports, but I want to run it on 80)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the port from 80 to say 82 or 83 and then you won't run into any conflicts.

So in the instructions where it references the port number as 61156:

```
Find <IISUrl>http://localhost:61156/</IISUrl> and change it to <IISUrl>http://devserver.com:61156/</IISUrl>
```

Simply change those to 82 or 83 where it references the 61156 port number and that should avoid any conflicts with the oft used port 80.

D