# using custom domain instead of localhost:* in IIS express

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis, localhost

I have created an MVC4 web application and I want to use my custom domain myApp.com instead of localHost:56605 . so I have added

```
127.0.0.1:56605  myApp.com
```

to the hosts file. 
2nd: I have gone to project properties in Visual studio 2012 and added myApp.com instead of localhost:56605. but when I click on Create virtual directory I got a warning indicating unable to create a virtual directory.
I also edited the applicationHost.config file too. but the problem still remains.

I have also searched in stackoverflow but most rely to this approach myapp:56605. I dont want to insert port number in the url.

how can I accomplish this?

Comment: You'll need to have IIS Express run on port 80 if you don't want to use a port number. The hosts file only affects DNS lookups.

Comment: could you explain more?

Comment: The hosts file only translates myapp.com to 127.0.0.1. The port number (56605) is completely separate. You can remove it from the hosts file and type myapp.com:65605 into your browser if you like.

Comment: @acfrancis I have done this. but I don't want to have port number in the url. I just want to have a clean URL like: myApp.com/people

Comment: If you don't specify the port number, the browser will default to 80. Can you run IIS Express on port 80?

Comment: I get Server Error in Application "DEFAULT WEB SITE" HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found. how can I solve this? visual studio run my app on a different port (56606). should I make any changes in IIS?

Comment: [This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178109.aspx) seems to have decent walk through about using a different port number. You need to use port 80 (the standard HTTP port) if you don't want to enter any port number in the URL. Also, http://stackoverflow.com/a/11250513/254973 has some instructions on how to get a different domain up and running (though it seems like you've got that up and running?)

Comment: @StevenV I did but it says port 80 is in use. Do you think the this question can have any answer? because I think if I dont want to use a port number I should deploy my app on server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

so what I did to fix this issue:

in the hosts file I added:

```
127.0.0.1 myApp.com
```

then in the `applicationhost.config` which is located in IISExpress in my document I edited binding section of my app like this:

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:myApp.com" />
<binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:myApp.com" />
```

then go to project properties in visual studio and in the web tab edite project url like this:

http://myapp.com

then click on create virtual directory, your virtual directory will created successfully. then your site using port 80. which shouldn't used by any other app in your pc. else you get an error indicating your port 80 is used by another process.

to fix this issue close skype, teamViewer, and in IIS manager all of the site you have created and using port 80 should be stopped.

finally you can successfully surf your site www.myApp.com
more explanation:

http://www.macaw.nl/weblog/2013/6/configuring-an-asp-net-project-for-development-with-ssl
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx

Answer (score 4):

I found a faster way. Change the applicationhost.config where you put localhost over ip directly (127.0.0.1).

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:55449:127.0.0.1" />
```

In the file hosts in system32 add the name of the domain:

```
127.0.0.1 domainname.com
```

So you can access by name your application running on iis express.

Comment: Adding binding for the loopback ip worked for me.

Many thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

> but when I click on Create virtual directory I got a warning indicating unable to create a virtual directory

-> this can be fixed if you run visual studio as an administrator