# Start Visual Studio 2010 debug with custom domain name not localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web, dns

I want to debug my web project but also want that when I press f5 key my domain name should be "projectabc.com".

I changed web properties of my project like below, but got the error.

[image]

My host file like below

[image]

Could you please help what is my mistake? I can browse my site on localhost If I select "Use Visual Studio Development Server". But as I said, I want to debug on a custom domain.

Thanks for help

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249633/make-localhost-a-custom-domain-in-iis-express